# How close can a circuit board be to an overhead power line without being effected by EMI?

Tags: grounding, emc, circuit-protection, power-engineering

I am researching a technology that will need to put some circuitry near a power line used on the electric grid and I was trying to determine how close can I get to the power lines with my circuit boards without causing issue due to EMI or other factors. My expectation for the technology is that the board will run within a one foot radius of the power lines and possibly other equipment such as transformers, but I am concerned with EMI and other factors disrupting my circuits. Does anyone have any experience with this and know how close they can be?

Some details: The circuit boards will be both grounded only via battery in some cases, and others will be grounded through a grounding wire or grounded material. Depending on guidance here I may adjust my design. My understanding is that the grounding should help with the EMI and other noise related issues.

Thanks!

Comment: what does this mean? `grounded only via battery`

Comment: I would recommend conductive shielding around your circuit board. Perhaps a metal box. For safety, you might want to have insulation around the metal box.

Comment: "Electric grid" could mean anything from 120 V to 1 MV. What voltages are you dealing with and at what current? If there's any chance that a spark can jump the gap then your grounding wire is going to be a problem. Hit the [edit] link and add the details into your question (and not in the comments).

Comment: If your box is going to go very close to HV power lines, then it must have no connection to stuff at low voltage or ground at all. Nothing. No grounding wire. No data wires. No power supply wires. It must therefore be battery operated, or draw its power from the HV line, perhaps via a current transformer, or from solar photo-voltaic. It must communicate without wires, so by radio, optically - either free-space or fibre-optics with either visible or IR, or along the HV wires themselves.

Comment: This issue comes up with utilities sharing their rights-of-way and poles with telephone and cable operators. The stand-off distances are specified by code. I suggest researching this to gain a regulatory understanding as well as an electrical one. At only one foot separation, your gear needs to be treated as high voltage, so it *cannot* have an electrical connection to anything that isn’t in the high voltage bubble.

Comment: You also need to describe to some extent what's on your circuit board and what it can tolerate.

Comment: **and others will be grounded through a grounding wire or grounded material.** That is a bad idea for any pole voltage.  Height of pole means minimum separation between line and ground.  You are providing a short cut.  No regulatory agency would approve it.